# У ссылки появились лишние пиксели, как избавиться от них?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Поставил header фиксированную высоту в 80px, добавил в него ссылку и в нее обернул картинку(высота 80px), но почему-то ссылка добавила лишние 3 пикселя. Как можно это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}

.header__container {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  height: 80px;
}

.basket {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header__link {}

#price {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header__group {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__group--price {
  background-color: #FF7C45;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9c48963e84.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header class="header">
  <div class="container header__container">
    <a href="#" class="header__link">
      <img class="header__logo" src="./images/logo.svg" alt="not-found">
    </a>
    <div class="header__group">
      <div class="header__group--price">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart basket"></i>
        <span id="price">100.00$</span>
      </div>
      <button class="header__button">Выйти</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня вроде 80px

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

:root {
  --mainColor: orange;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

header {
  --widthHeader: 80px;
  max-height: var(--widthHeader);
}

button {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.header__link {
  display: block;
}

.header__container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__link img {
  max-height: var(--widthHeader);
  height: 100%;
}

.header--price {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.btn {
  --anotherColor: black;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
  color: var(--anotherColor);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid var(--anotherColor);
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-property: border-color, background-color, color;
}

.btn:hover {
  --mainColor: black;
  --anotherColor: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9c48963e84.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__container flex">
      <a href="#" class="header__link">
        <img class="header__logo" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" alt="not-found">
      </a>
        <div class="header--price">
          <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart basket"></i>
          <span id="price">100.00$</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn">Выйти</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.header{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
}
.header__container{
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.header__logo{
    height: 80px;
}
.basket{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.header__link{
    max-height: 80px;
}
#price{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.header__group{
    width: 250px;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

}
.header__group--price{
    background-color: #FF7C45;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.header__button{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cinema World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css">
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9c48963e84.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
        <div class="container header__container">
            <a href="#" class="header__link">
                <img class="header__logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/0UyDfgp.png" alt="not-found">
            </a>
            <div class="header__group">
                <div class="header__group--price">
                    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart basket"></i>
                    <span id="price">100.00$</span>
                </div>
                <button class="header__button">Выйти</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </body>
```

вот так? добавить к классу `header__link{ max-height: 80px};`

Comment: Способ рабочий и действительно помогает, но разве так правильно? Я хотел понять принцип из-за чего ссылке накидываются лишние пиксели, если высота указана у родителей фиксированная, у картинки тоже своя высота есть.

Comment: возможно дело в line-height, который стоит у body

Comment: Все обнулено через reset.css

Comment: не знаю даже, сложный случай) ставлю ссылке position: absolute, а она все равно 83 пикселя, родитель получается не накладывает на нее запрет или накладывает не полностью...

Comment: @Torin_21 зачем вы всем элементам всё время указываете высоту  и ширину фиксированную? Это же неудобно, используйте padding